# Ender 3 Pro Glass Bed print fails midway

Tags: creality-ender-3, adhesion

Since upgrading to the glass bed my prints are failing right after the point where I finally feel confident that they are adhered well and printing smoothly. They seem to be coming loose from the bed and dragging around following the extruder while it prints into the air (or worse it builds up around the nozzle bc the print is moving along directly under the nozzle). I thought it was an issue with the print settings I was using so I went back to a .gcode I have printed dozens of times on the old bed with great success and it also had the same issue.

I had issues with initial adhesion and tried gluestick and hairspray. There still seems to be a little issue with the PLA not catching hold immediately which can cause a little glob/tail to form. Once the filament sticks it does it doesn't have any gaps or thin spots. If those tails from the beginning of the print snag on the extruder as it passes over that area again it will pull them up but if it doesn't the new layers all lay down smoothly and don't seem to have gaps or get the nozzle dragging through the filament. On new files, I tried increasing the heat to 65 °C but didn't seem to fix this issue. The old files are set at bed temp 60 °C and extruder 200 °C.

I was able to print a tiny (1x2 cm and 7.5 mm) item at 0.08 mm layer height and it's beautiful. Everything that is getting messed up is at least 1 cm tall when it fails.

Comment: basically you either have a discrepancy in where the top of the part should be vs where it is or an issue with the part curling and detaching due to thermal issues.  check bed leveling, verify the bed moves how much it thinks it moves via calipers, and check the filament diameter vs your programmed settings.  Also try to print a bit cooler; you need to find the sweet spot that is hot enough to stick but not so hot that the part curls a lot when it cools.

Comment: Sounds like either a leveling problem or a greasing glass bed... Can you share a photo of the underside of the prints?